# Constructing a PDA to accept the language {a^i b^j c^k where i,j,k>0 and i<=j<=2k}

Tags: formal-languages, pushdown-automata

Can anybody help me out with this? If I try to compare $a$'s with $b$'s to check if $j\ge i$ then I won't be able to compare the same number of $b$'s with the number of $c$'s that is to check if $j\le 2k$.

Comment: Have you already considered the possibility that there is no PDA for this language?

Comment: actually i did not consider that ...... so i assume the said language cannot be accepted by a PDA but instead it can be accepted by a turing machine